How to teach high school students to analyze diagrams in a proof?
I work as a math intervention teacher with high school sophomores who are currently taking geometry. The sequence of instruction is as followed (so far this year):

Introduction to geometry - naming geometric figures, segment/angle addition postulate, midpoint, distance, bisectors
Deductive reasoning - writing conditional statements, their converses, and biconditionals (if both are true); two-column algebraic and geometric proofs
Angles formed by two lines cut by a transversal
Congruent triangles

In working with them, I have struggled to engage them in critical thinking about proofs. The proofs always have "givens" and "prove" statements.
If these students encounter a blank space in the proof, whether it be a statement or a reason, they freeze and don't know how to proceed. Below are two examples of proofs where every student did not know how to proceed with proving that the triangles are congruent.

I think it is a mixture of under-confidence in math in general, not having these theorems/concepts memorized, and low motivation. I prompt them a lot with "what does it mean to bisect?" "what does a midpoint do?" "where is this angle on the diagram?" "mark up the diagram with the given information," etc. but I am constantly asking these questions. How can I shift the responsibility of asking the questions from me to the students so they can complete proofs?

Personally when I look at two-column high school proofs I think "wow; I'm glad math is nothing like this." I can't imagine trying to convince teenagers to do this. How do you even begin? Do you have really easy exercises for them to start with? And then the ones in the question right now are the payoff at the end? Maybe if you have really easy ones where they learn the "rules" and the "moves" they could be convinced this is a kind of puzzle game for them to work out like a sudoku? I am honestly asking; I haven't taught this age group.

@ChrisCunningham I would have assumed that the students have some easier tasks first, or at least being explained how to play this two-column game (I'm in one voice with Marissa's comment as well as user52817's answer here. This proof format is not inherently bad. I'm actually surprised one can be negatively surprised just by looking at this. Did you personally have bad experience doing this?

@justhalf I did two-column proofs as a student and enjoyed them. I felt at the time that I was doing real proofs, and I still feel that way. Nevertheless, the examples in this post really do not sit well with me. If these are meant to be advanced examples for students who have already done easier tasks then why are the students not doing their own proofs from scratch? Why are they filling in the blanks of someone else's outline? More seriously, why do the outlines not show a coherent proof strategy? If SSS is to be used, why are angle facts being proved that won't be needed? (Or if SAS...

... or ASA is to be used, why are unneeded length facts being proved?) As Marissa's comment suggests, students will at some point apply a postulate or theorem with multiple hypotheses, and will need to state that the hypotheses have all been verified. At that point it will be clear that many lines of these proofs are never cited in subsequent lines, which makes these poor examples of clear and convincing communication. The fill-in-the-blank format also turns the task into one of guessing someone else's proof strategy (statement side) or coming up with the right set of...

... words to put (reason side) These are important, but secondary to the main task of learning how to reason. I can see why students might find these kinds of exercises frustrating and boring.

I totally share the frustration.  And I had a low Bayesian estimate of how this Q&A would work out.  But it's actually been a worthwhile discussion.  I think  the issues are actually more with the redundancy and confusion over which proof approach to use, versus just the two column table.  The reflexive WTF, which I had too, is actually not from the format, but from the poor exercises, but being blamed on the format.

@ChrisCunningham I've actually come around a little bit on the idea that a two-column proof is not the worst thing in the universe.  I just think that they should be taught more as an organizational device, in the same way that students taking English composition classes are taught to create outlines.  The two-column proof is not the final outcome---it is an organizational tool which can be used to structure an argument, which then needs to be written up in proper English. :/

I have a degree in computer science and I've done a tone of math to get there, including geometry, and I don't have the slightest idea what I'm supposed to do here. I think your students feel just like me, they look at this, and it's like looking at some Lovecraftian incomprehensible alien. Looking at the first problem, should I just write "this is a given" for nearly all rows, and then in the end cite some particular theorem on why two triangles with equal sides and angles are equal? I'm genuinely lost about this format.

@Davor This might give you an idea of what you are supposed to do: when analyzing the second grid, I notice an unknown Statement adjacent to the 'Vertical Angles Theorem' in the Reason column.  This prompts me to recall the theorem, which involves the angles formed by two intersecting lines. Examining the diagram, I observed two intersecting lines, leading me to infer that the missing statement is $\angle POQ \cong \angle SOR$. This effectively guided me to  analyze the diagram as desired in the title of the OP. The format is scaffolding for learners not ready to write original proofs.

@Davor I've heard similar things from parents complaining about the Common Core:  "I took math in school, and I have a bachelor's degree in [some field], but I have no idea what is happening here!"  Fair enough, but that only means that it isn't something that you were taught, not that it is somehow mysterious or inappropriate for students.  In the context in which these things are taught, it is certainly learnable---it just requires instruction.

See, for example, the multiplication algorithm which most of us know and "love", but which was once considered strange and foreign: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6OaYPVueW4 .

@Davor as with any other times when looking at student exercises, especially high school and below, I'd always assume the homework is not the first time the student sees the format. Many learning tools would feel alien to someone first time seeing it (that's why it's common for student homework to be viral for its weirdness), but once you got it explained in class, it's usually not hard to see what it's supposed to mean and how it helps learning. That's usually my take :)

@XanderHenderson - the problem isn't that I'd be unable to learn how to solve it, the problem is that it doesn't teach anything about logical deduction. It's a puzzle game. And I'm sorry if I offend you, but American education really isn't a model I'd ever want to adopt. I'm quite happy I've never seen this thing in my life.

It is easy for mathematically inclined individuals (myself included) to criticize the two-column proofs of high school geometry as artificial and unrepresentative of the thought processes mathematicians use when writing proofs. They seem overly procedural. However, it is worthwhile to consider why this format persists and what value it provides.
For better or worse, since the late 19th century, high school geometry in the United States has been designated as the place for students to learn the "art of demonstration." Patricio Herbst's work, Establishing a Custom of Proving in American School Geometry: Evolution of the Two-Column Proof in the Early Twentieth Century, explores how the two-column format brought stability to geometry education. It enabled teachers to effectively teach proof construction while providing students with a clear and structured way to demonstrate their understanding. If you do not appreciate this structure, then I invite you to grade and critique about ten "paragraph proofs" written by beginning students who are novice to proof!
Another factor influencing the procedural approach to introducing proof is the content knowledge of in-service secondary school mathematics teachers. In Secondary School Mathematics Teachers' Conceptions of Proof, Eric Knuth notes that "many teachers hold limited views of the nature of proof in mathematics and demonstrate inadequate understandings of what constitutes proof." Given these realities, the structure provided by two-column proofs emerges as a practical approach. It offers a clear framework for both teaching and learning.
In fact, it seems reasonable that any team tasked with developing educational materials, such as textbooks for high school geometry, would inevitably devise a system resembling two-column proofs. Their utility in simplifying and standardizing the teaching of proof makes them a natural choice, even if they emphasize procedural knowledge over creativity.

I support this answer. I'd also add things like: (1) computerized proof assistants like Isabelle absolutely have proofs documented this way (statement and supporting "by" clause), (2) graduate texts (e.g., Casella/Berger Statistical Inference) that when things get symbolically hairy break into exactly this statement and side-justification mode, which I find very helpful.

As an non-American who has never seen this format in his life, this thing is horrendous. The problem isn't that it's in two columns, or that it's broken in lines. That's normal. The problem is that steps on the left are already given, with some missing, turning it into a weird guessing puzzle game that has nothing to do with the process of constructing an actual proof. This is like having people draw by numbers and calling it painting class.

No experience with this, other than as a student. But I know from working with school children that they, and I as well, feel a sense of panic when faced with an assignment where the creator of the assignment is evidently trying to lead the student along a certain path, but it's not clear what path or why.
So my suggestion would be to dispense with the "Prove" line and dispense with the two-column table. Just hand students the list of givens, and set them the task of drawing as many inferences as they can. Tell them to start with simple, obvious things, and see if they can use those to build up to less obvious things. If they need more help, you can ask leading questions: Are there any lines you know are equal? (How do you know?) Are there any angles you know are equal? (How do you know?) Are there any triangles you know are equal? (How do you know?) Are there any lines you think may be equal (based on the figure, say), but aren't sure about? What extra information would be helpful in deciding this? (And likewise for angles, triangles, etc.)
Another question for reflection: is any of the given information redundant (in that it could have been inferred from the other givens)? That's especially pertinent in both your examples, which are over determined. I think that's a big factor explaining why these examples are difficult for students. The outlined proofs are not suggesting any particular proof strategy, but are leaving many options open. So some information that is written down in the table won't be used in any particular final proof. That is why I think it is better to start with an open-ended assignment. You can then ask students to narrow their proof down to only those statements that are absolutely necessary.
If the two-column format is necessary for your curriculum, you can have them fill in the table as the very final step. Perhaps they could put a mark next to those statements that weren't actually used in the end.

First off, let's get this out of the way: those proof outlines are bad (those in particular and that style in general). I only really looked at the first proof and of all the statements listed, only the third, sixth, and eighth need to be said. Why repeat something that's written and drawn directly above? Also, why is statement four even there? [Marissa brings up a good point in the comments about repeating givens. Of course, repeating givens in a proof is standard practice and something I do myself so I'm not against it. In this case, I consider the diagram's markings to be a repetition whenever the reader needs it, in particular when referring back to the figure to match up sides and angles and verify SAS or whatever is used. But that's just my personal preference; ignore it if it seems dumb.]
I think you need to go through the proofs as they're done in real life. You want to show that two triangles are congruent, so you start by thinking of ways you can show this. There's SSS, SAS, etc. Then you look at what you have and decide which is easiest. You might not have much luck with that approach either, but if this way isn't working it's worth a shot.
edit: Let me add more detail to my last paragraph, which isn't especially helpful as it stands. Looking at the diagram for the first proof, we have, starting from the common side $MP$ and going clockwise in the top triangle, SASAS. The first angle and the last side require explanation, which in both cases is simply invoking a definition (bisector or midpoint). So pick any one of SSS, SAS, ASA, AAS, or different SAS.
Have you just learned about angle bisectors? Then focus on $\angle PMN$ and $\angle PMR$ and use ASA. Just learned about midpoints? Then $NP=RP$ so use SAS (I personally don't bother with cumbersome notation like $\overline{NP}\cong \overline{RP}$). I asked why statement four is even there, but if you've just learned that the angles in a triangle add to $180$ degrees, or if you want to discuss right angles, then go ahead and use statement four! Do they tend to overlook things like $MP=MP$ because it's almost too obvious? Then use SSS. The point is to pick one. Right now the proof outline includes statements from like five different proofs, so of course the students are confused.
Do you work with the whole class at once or individually? If the former, can you break them into groups and ask one group to use SSS, another SAS, and so on? If the latter, can you ask the student to provide several proofs, first using whatever method they want, then using a different one (maybe one you suggest)?

I have been a high school geometry teacher. A lot of teaching high school geometry is emphasizing that you need to verify all of the conditions of a theorem before you can draw the conclusion. As a result, yes we do want to make students write out that all of the conditions are verified.

@Marissa Are you referring to my annoyance at having to repeat the givens? Normally I'd agree but (1) the proof is so short I think they can be only obliquely referenced ("NP=RP by definition of midpoint, and combined with the hypotheses MNP cong. MRP by SAS in that order") and (2) students can be so confused (I've taught geometry as well) that they don't connect the statement to the givens and try to somehow prove it ("uh, MN cong MR because they're mirror images..."). In the end, if a proof is a convincing argument, can you honestly say mine above is not a correct proof?

But I think you have to realize "what I like, am used to" may not gibe with the on the ground objectives, in teaching high school geometry in the USA.  That's why I cautioned the questioner to talk to people other than on this forum, which is very slanted to college teaching.  The interaction from Marissa, ought to e cautionary of your own blind spot.  (And FWIW, I don't mind the kids repeating each element of the proof, including "given" as a possible rationale.  I remember doing that, also.

You do have a good point about the whole SASAS thing though.  And it's obvious from the end of the table that things are heading to SSS, so the angles are extra info, confusing to a neophyte.

You both raise good points and I really do agree with both of you except in rare cases, so I'll edit when I have the time to make that more clear.

This is going to be a long, wishy washy answer, but just trying to help.
The TLDR is (1) talk to real geometry teachers, not found here, much, and (2) do easier problems.

(1)
It's been so long for me, that it's hard to really opine here.  The amount of detail seems a bit bewildering, but maybe I didn't feel like that that when I took the class.
In addition to the challenge of the geometry itself, there is the pedagogical challenge.  I guess for students in general and then turbocharged since you are doing "intervention".
I wonder if you could look at their textbook (or some variants, if it's not helping) or ask what other teachers in your situation have done?  It's totally an on topic question, but as a practical matter this forum doesn't really have good coverage of high school, especially geometry.  I just worry you will get a lot of responses here that are from people that are so distant from the topic (pedagogically or content-wise) that they will mostly complain about the bewildering detail.  And this is how I sort of feel, but I don't know that cutting it really helps either or is justified.
If you Google, you can find a lot of little blogs of teachers--maybe reach out.  Also, in person ask the regular teachers for advice, as colleagues.  Don't feel like you have to figure it out all yourself.  A lot of why you are the "intervention" teacher is not that you are better (content or pedagogy) than the regular teaches, but just that you have time and attention to the "intervened".  So don't be bashful to talk to them.

(2)
I also wonder if these problems are a little harder than optimal.  I know you want to get there eventually, but perhaps training on simpler ones would be better.
Like for the first problem, I think the given about congruence of the two angles is not needed nor is the given about the bisecting angle.  Those are red herrings, extra details, which may confuse.  (I think.)
You want to get to SSS "side-side-side" to prove the end statement about the two triangles.  (I'm assuming they have previously learned this theorem and may use it as a tool, now.)  One side equivalence is given, the other side is "definition of midpoint", and the last side is "common" (congruent to itself, I guess).  So why all the details about angles?

I can offer a perspective, even if not solutions.
What is proof
Proof is a way a mathematician convinces themself and others that some claim is true. Mathematics is a sphere of life or a field of science where this can be done quite rigorously.
The big risk with the column proof thing is that the students have not understood this, maybe because the teacher has not focused on communicating this, and the method is instead taught as an arbitrary algorithm. (This is the same risk as with any other algorithm; they are not particularly motivating or easy to learn if you have no idea what is happening.)
Sociomathematical norms
Sociomathematical norms are the social norms in the classroom (or some other community) that are about mathematics in particular. In particular: what is a valid argument in mathematics? Can you just look at an example or two? Why or why not? Draw some pictures? Eventually: present a structured proof? But surely this is not where you should start, or what you should assume the norms in a classroom to be.
What do do
You need to establish the path: argumentation -> argumentation in mathematics -> idea of a proof -> why is every step true -> write this down in a particular format (if really desired, because really, who cares about this format?).
Of course, sometimes the "idea of a proof" parts has a lot of complications, like several steps of "maybe this is useful" and "does this work", and often involves sketching out some tentative pictures etc.
This might include the skill of perseverance, or not giving up when things are not easy, which some students might not be used to. They might have learnt that in mathematics, you always know what to do and then do it, or otherwise it is hard and you ask for help. Struggling with a task for a longer time might be foreign and something you need to establish as the norm.


I think it is a mixture of under-confidence in math in general, not having these theorems/concepts memorized, and low motivation.

If you have this belief, why not ... fix it?
Give them a cheat sheet with all of the theorems you are using written out.
Third Angle Theorem?  Written out.
Then give them a pile of problems using those Theorems.  They can start out really simple; in fact, you'll want them to solve simple problems using those Theorems until they are super fast and accurate with them.  This builds confidence, provides them with usage-memorization experience, and "I got it" provides some motivation.
Once they have the Theorem internalized, as evidenced by speed and accuracy, provide slightly harder problems.  Only slightly.  Use more than one Theorem - TWO OF THEM.  Once that is mastered, three whole theorems in a row!
Go back and have problems where you have to identify which Theorem is being used, and use a Theorem - single blanks.  Get 95% accuracy at this with your entire pool of theorems.  It doesn't matter if it is just pattern recognition that gets the kids to 95%.
Upgrading to two in a problem, but not two in a row, is a big step; and if you aren't 95%+ accurate at single blank versions of the problem, it is hellishly difficult, as errors in one compound.
Mix double-blanks in with single-blank problems.  The single-blank problems keep the kid convinced they do understand something, and the double-blanks provide a stretch.  Hand-hold the double blank problems sometimes, like have a single-blank problem, then a second 2nd blank problem, then a double-blank problem that is literally the two single-blank problems glued together.
Then overlap the two single-blank problems in the same way, so the double-blank version is the two single-blanks adjacent to each other.
Teaching multiple people at the edge of their group's capabilities means that anyone who isn't at the edge of the group will be left behind.  Learning proof patterns is a pattern-recognition task, and learning patterns requires repetition.
You can, for people who have a very solid foundation, skip ahead in the pattern recognition without mastering earlier patterns.  This requires the student to internally do the practice or pick it up while working on more advanced problems.  When it works, it lets you cover material faster; but what it really tends to do is leave any student with a flaw in their foundation behind to fail.

Can your students with 95%+ accuracy and high speed solve "single blank" double column proofs?

If they can't, the problems you provided above will be like asking a kid without working hands to climb a tree.  Some will succeed, but most will fail.
This is for all kinds of single blanks.  Single blank on the left and right (find the missing statement, and find the missing theorem).
Do this with a cheat sheet - a print out of every theorem you are using - in order to hit 95%.  Then, if you want them to do it on more complex proofs without the sheet, remove the sheet and get them up to 95%+ again.

Can your students with 95%+ accuracy and high speed solve "double blank" double column proofs, with the blanks NOT being adjacent?

While this doesn't seem a pile harder than #1, it is a step.  Hopefully students who have mastered #1 will master #2 quickly.  If not, you have to iterate on it to understand the issue.

Can your students with 95%+ accuracy and high speed solve "double blank" double column proofs, with the blanks BEING adjacent?

This is much, much harder.  But after #1 and #2 there is some hope.
There are 5 kinds of adjacent double blanks.  Both statement and theorem missing is 1, then there are adjacent lines where theorem is missing twice, statement is missing twice, and two different ways for one theorem and one statement to be missing.
Getting this skill up to 95%+ accuracy (first with a cheat sheet, then without) is going to be a big step.
Only after all 3 of these steps are 95%+ accuracy and high speed should students be considered ready to solve that 7 blank proof with even 50% accuracy and slow speed.
If you instead simply teach them all of the rules then throw the 7 blank question at them without having them first master the simpler versions, what I expect to happen is the students with an extremely solid foundation, high internal motivation, and good self-practice skills to be the only ones to succeed.  And those are the students who succeed almost no matter what you do.
A big problem with the mastery based approach is that you have to handle some students mastering the material much faster than others.  You have to keep them engaged while you also help those who are taking longer catch up.
